# This Vs. That while referring to something

Tags: word-choice

I'm calling my friend telling him that my brother will call him with a week. After **this/that call (of my brother)**, you will get the new car within 30 days.

I'd like to take the part (of my brother) out of the sentence. I feel like using **that** refers more to my brother's call. I would not like my friend to think of our current call. She should think of the call of my brother. Is using **that** services that purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes I do think 'that' is the correct one for this context.

You calling your friend:
"Hey bla bla bla. My brother will call you within a week. After **that** call, you'll get the new car within 30 days."

**But**, if your friend's English understanding is below intermediate, she might misinterpret it.

It's easier to understand if you say something like:
"My brother will call you within a week. After **his** call (my brother's), you'll get the new car within 30 days."